# I was wondering if somebody could guess what the attached photo's lens spec could be? I'm aware it's rather edited but any guesses?

Tags: photo-editing, digital

[image]
Love this image but not sure what camera spec I'd need to get such a crisp look?

Comment: Why do you think it's about the lens, rather than the skill of the photographer, the lighting and many, many other things?

Comment: Oh, I'm aware it's not just about the lens, I guess I'm asking what would be a step in the right direction in terms of camera spec.

Comment: The rich contrast and color along with the look of the out of focus areas reminds me Zeiss 100 Makro. It is hard to guess in general and even harder with such a low res compressed picture.

Answer (score 1):

Your picture is far too small to give a real impression, but there is nothing exceptional in the technical part. Any cheap DSRL can take a shot like this, with minimal processing.

What you need is knowledge about boket, depth of focus, light distribution, composition, color choices, pose, exposure, etc. All things that are experience, skill, and knowledge of the photographer (and the model), none of it is in the camera or lens.

I'd *guess* this is an 80mm lens, wide open. But that is not a required part of making the shot.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I realise that my question probably sounds really naive, I'm just trying to learn photography from scratch and particularly like this image

Comment: Or maybe a nifty-fifty on an APS-C body?

Comment: If want you *really* want to know is "how can I take an image similar to this one?", that's the question to ask, not "what lens do I need to take this image?". [Be sure to explain *what* it is about the image that you like](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions)

Answer (score 1):

The 'look' makes me think it's probably in the 135mm or above range and reasonably fast. There is some vignetting but not sure if that was added afterwards,is due to the lens or the area of lighting behind the subject.
The out of focus area (bokeh) is a bit odd looking but again without the being able to see the original in high res, it's impossible to tell if it's been manipulated to create that. If you want to recreate that look, any fast lens 85mm plus along with some pretty backlight would work.

Answer (score 0):

> Love this image but not sure what camera spec I'd need to get such a crisp look?

The "look" you like has more to do with lighting, depth of field, and a bit of vignetting than with a particular lens, at least as far as one can see from that small example. You could take a similar shot with an entry-level DSLR and an inexpensive 50mm f/1.8 lens, but you'd probably also need some lighting equipment.